# Android Inner join query error

Tags: android-sqlite

I am creating notepad and now I am facing issue when I am trying to implement join with dynamically passing id into it and also using Order by. it is giving SQLiteexception near "=".

I don't know what is the reason I am writing this query:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_TASKNOTE + " FROM " + TABLE_TODOTASK
            + " INNER JOIN" + TABLE_TODOTASK_DETAILS + "ON " + KEY_TASKID + "=" + KEY_TASK_DETAILS_TASKID + " WHERE " 
            + KEY_TASK_TASKLISTID + "=" + tasklist_Id + " ORDER BY " + KEY_TASK_DETAILS_DUEDATE;
```

CONSTANTS:

```
// TASK table name
private static final String TABLE_TODOTASK = "todotask";
// TASKLIST Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_TASKID = "Id";
private static final String KEY_TASKNOTE = "tasknote";
private static final String KEY_TASKDUEDATE = "duedate";
private static final String KEY_TASKCOMPLETED = "taskcompleted";
private static final String KEY_TASK_TASKLISTID = "TaskList_id";

// TASKDETAILS table name
private static final String TABLE_TODOTASK_DETAILS = "todotaskdetails";
// TASKDETAILS Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_TASK_DETAILS_ID = "ID";
private static final String KEY_TASK_DETAILS_TASKID = "Task_id";
private static final String KEY_TASK_DETAILS_DUEDATE = "taskduedate";
private static final String KEY_TASK_DETAILS_EVENT = "taskevent";
private static final String KEY_TASKDETAILS_REMINDER = "taskreminder";
private static final String KEY_TASKDETAILS_REPEAT = "taskrepeat";
private static final String KEY_TASKDETAILS_PRIORITY = "taskpriority";
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: Can you include the declarations for all of those constants, please?

Comment: use table prefix for inner join

Comment: (Also, FYI, it looks like you're missing spaces around `TABLE_TODOTASK_DETAILS`, after `JOIN` and before `ON`.)

Comment: @Michelle, I have mentioned those, please check now.

Answer (score 0):

For inner join, you need to use `tablename1.fieldName = tablename2.fieldName`, but you used only `field name = field name`. Add the table prefixes like this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_TASKNOTE + " FROM " + TABLE_TODOTASK
            + " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_TODOTASK_DETAILS + " ON " + TABLE_TODOTASK+"."+KEY_TASKID + "=" + TABLE_TODOTASK_DETAILS +"."+KEY_TASK_DETAILS_TASKID + " WHERE " 
            + KEY_TASK_TASKLISTID + "=" + tasklist_Id + " ORDER BY " + KEY_TASK_DETAILS_DUEDATE;
```

Simple example of inner join

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1
INNER JOIN table_name2 
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you could explain what you changed from OP's original query.

Comment: for inner join using tablename1.fieldName = tablename2.fieldName, but you used only field name = field name

Comment: first try without  where condition and order by